# JProfiler Agent issue with id and config parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, jprofiler

We are currently using JProfiler 8.0.4 in [Prepare for Profiling"](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/profiling/modes.html) mode on our Cent OS machines together with Tomcat 6 and Java 7. We use JProfiler with a floating license. We extracted the JProfiler Linux Archive on the remote servers.

Tomcat is managed by Tanuki Wrapper. Here is our Config

```
wrapper.java.additional.101=-agentpath:${jprofiler.path}/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait
```

This works well and when starting up we find this in the logs

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.872 | JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.872 | JProfiler> Protocol version 38
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.872 | JProfiler> Using JVMTI
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.872 | JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> 64-bit library
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Starting up without initial configuration.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:41.873 | JProfiler> Native library initialized
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:06:42.074 | JProfiler> VM initialized
```

Finally we are connecting with our JProfiler Clients to the agents and everythings fine.

As mentioned in [1](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/helptopics/profiling/modes.html)

> , it's also possible to append ,config=[config file] and ,id=[id] parameters to instruct the profiling agent to take the profiling settings from a particular session in a particular config file. If you connect with the same profiling settings, no classes will have to be retransformed.

but if we add config and id like this
wrapper.java.additional.101=-agentpath:${jprofiler.path}/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849,nowait,id=${jprofiler.id},config=${jprofiler.config.path} the VM cannot start up because JProfiler asks for an license.

```
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Don't wait for frontend to connect.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Protocol version 38
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Using JVMTI
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> 64-bit library
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Using config file /path/to/config/jprofiler-config.xml (id: 100)
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.475 | JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.476 | JProfiler> Native library initialized
ERROR  | wrapper  | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.614 | JVM exited while loading the application.
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.614 | JProfiler> VM initialized
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.614 | JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.615 | JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.615 | JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
INFO   | jvm 5    | main    | 2014/03/04 10:05:30.615 | JProfiler> ERROR: Invalid license key.
```

Here are my questions:

1. Anyone knows how to tell the agent about the license?
2. Anyone used this settings in a production setup?

Regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction is really unnecessary and will be removed in JProfiler 8.1.

As of 8.0, the license key has to be in the config file if the config parameter is specified. You can copy the entire config file from %USERPROFILER.jprofiler8\config.xml or $HOME/.jprofiler8/config.xml rather than exporting it, then the license key will be available for the agent.

Comment: Thanks you Ingo! It works! I just extracted the license part and inserted it in the servers config file.